# Send Uncompressed Request to Nginx Proxy

Tags: asp.net, nginx, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My website is running Nginx as a reverse proxy that is in front of  a ASP.net application server.  The ASP app server does not support large request bodies compressed with with gzip.

Is it possible for Nginx to decompress the HTTP request before sending it to the ASP application server?

Comment: I attempted to clarify and simplify the question by rewriting.  Please confirm it's correct?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.pataliebre.net/howto-make-nginx-decompress-a-gzipped-request.html#.XgUCu2T7RPZ

Comment: @Justin any luck ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have nginx with lua support or openresty, you can use lua-zlib module to do this.

```
-- Handle request
local zlib = require 'zlib'

myStr = nil
if ngx.req.get_headers()['Content-Encoding'] == 'gzip' then

    ngx.req.read_body()
    local myStr = zlib.inflate()(ngx.var.request_body, 'finish')

    ngx.req.clear_header('Content-Encoding')
    ngx.req.clear_header('Content-Length')
    ngx.req.set_body_data(myStr)
end
```

Source:

https://notes.ayushsharma.in/2016/10/decompressing-request-using-gzip-with-nginx
http://www.pataliebre.net/howto-make-nginx-decompress-a-gzipped-request.html#.VfgySp2qqko

Answer (score 0):

I would direct you to this site http://www.pataliebre.net/howto-make-nginx-decompress-a-gzipped-request.html#.Xgslz0czZPZ, it contains usefule snippets of code that should work for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **client_max_body_size**

step to change

1> vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

2> add this

```
http {
  #all other configurations . . . 
  client_max_body_size: 10M; #add this thing
}
```

3> sudo nginx -t

if every thing ok then restart your server and check otherwise check for your syntex error.

4> sudo service nginx restart

In case above steps not worked for you can stop gzip by this

```
server {
    gzip off;
    ...
}
```

**and repeat step 3 and 4**